# Do a grep of a group of files about a range of dates in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date

I have some rotative files, rotatitve because i have 5 files, and it files save logs of the all day. And if the first  file is full the logs are saved in the second, and if the second is full, the logs are saved in the third file, and if the last file is full the content of the first file is deleted and the logs are saved in the first file.
One file is for example:

```
$cat log1
2013-06-09 08:00  Error1  08x000001  user2
2013-06-09 08:00  Error1  08x000001  user3
2013-06-09 08:01  Error2  08x000002 user4
2013-06-09 08:02  Error3  08x000003  user5     
              .
              . 
              .
2013-06-09 12:22  Error9  08x900009  user5
2013-06-09 12:22  Error8  08x011011  user1
```

The problem is that i need read the logs, and do a grep of a range of time.

For example i need the logs of the 2013-06-09 between 08:00 and 11:00.

I.e. the lines with hour: 08:00, 08:01, 08:02, 08:03, ..., 11:00 and date 2013-06-09

And with a grep i can look the date, but i do not know how can i extract the lines of a range of hours.

Comment: How can a file be full?

Comment: Some logging software can limit the size of the log files, so the OP probably means that the log file is at maximum size.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific problem, with round hours:

```
grep '^2013-06-09 \(08*\|09*\|10*\|11:00\)'
```

should do.

Comment: And if the hour has seconds?

Comment: what about finding entries between `2013-06-09 08:30` and `2013-06-10 23:30` ?

Comment: But the problem is that the complete errors has numbers, but if i do a grep to this way the grep will show me lines with other hours, but, with the number

Comment: @Kent will still work by trivial adaptation. I also mentionned _for your specific problem_. `;)`

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle sorry, I don't understand your comment. Maybe you were commenting on another solution... (I'd randomly say KeepCalmAndCarryOn's solution).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf it could work, but how long your regex would be? the boundary could cross years, regex is not good to do math comparison/calculation.

Comment: @Kent thanks for your comment and don't worry I fully understand what you mean.

Comment: And how can i do if i need the date in a varianble because i need a crontab, for example. i need do it everyday. Then i need do grep with date=`date +%Y/%m/%d` grep '$date \(08*\|09*\|10*\|11:00\)'. But with a variable with the date do not works

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle Then use another method. Kent's one is good for that, just make sure you use proper quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use egrep. you can then pipe that back into grep to get the date, or even do it as one egrep

```
$ egrep "0[8-9]:" log
2013-06-09 08:00  Error1  user2
2013-06-09 08:00  Error1  user3
2013-06-09 08:01  Error2  user2
2013-06-09 08:02  Error3  user5
2013-06-09 09:03  Error3  user5
```

and

```
$ egrep "(0[8-9]|1[0-1]):" a
2013-06-09 08:00  Error1  user2
2013-06-09 08:00  Error1  user3
2013-06-09 08:01  Error2  user2
2013-06-09 08:02  Error3  user5
2013-06-09 09:03  Error3  user5
2013-06-09 10:02  Error3  user5
2013-06-09 10:02  Error3  user5
2013-06-09 11:02  Error3  user5
```

Comment: But this egrep do the search only by hour, i need by hour and by date

Comment: well you could pipe the result into another grep `...|grep 2013-06-09` or do it all in one `egrep "2013-06-09 0[8-9]:(01|02|03|04|05)" file`

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at your log file:

```
2013-06-09 08:00  Error1  user2
2013-06-09 08:00  Error1  user3
2013-06-09 08:01  Error2  user2
2013-06-09 08:02  Error3  user5
2013-06-09 09:03  Error3  user5
2013-06-09 10:02  Error3  user5
2013-06-09 10:02  Error3  user5
2013-06-09 11:02  Error3  user5
```

What if we remove the formatting from the time stamp?

```
201306090800  Error1  user2
201306090800  Error1  user3
201306090801  Error2  user2
201306090802  Error3  user5
201306090903  Error3  user5
201306091002  Error3  user5
201306091002  Error3  user5
201306091102  Error3  user5
```

Now, it will be a lot easier getting a range of dates and time! Let's see what we can work up.

Let's try a test:

```
sed -E 's/([[:digit:]]{4})-([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{2}) ([[:digit:]]{2}):([[:digit:]]{2})/\1\2\3\4\5/' $logfile
```

The sed is a *stream editor*, and I'm using the *substitute* command (that's the `s`). The command is in the form of:

```
 sed 's/old/new/' $logfile
```

This takes each line of the `$logfile` and replaces the first instance of `old` with `new` and prints the changed line.

The `old` is not a string of letters, but a *regular expression*. Regular expressions allow me to describe what I'm looking for. It's a very powerful concept.

The `[[:digit:]]` represents any digit on my line and the `{4}` means there must be four of them. That matches the date. The parentheses are *capture groups*. Basically, I'm capturing each part of the date as a separate entity.

Here is a more detailed explaination:

```
([[:digit:]]{4}) - Matches the four digit year
-                  Matches the dash after the year
([[:digit:]]{2})   Matches the two digit month
-                  Matches the dash after the month
([[:digit:]]{2})   Matches the two digit day of month
                   Matches the space between the date and time
([[:digit:]]{2})   Matches the two digit hour
:                  Matches the colon separator between the hours and minutes
([[:digit:]]{2})   Matches the minutes
```

Remember the parentheses? I can substitute the various parts of the date and time string to replace the entire string

```
\1   Year
\2   Month
\3   Date of Month
\4   Hour
\5   Minute
```

Take a look at my sed command and see if you can see each of these parts.

Can I use `awk`. Now that I've reformatted my line to remove the formatting of the time, I can use awk to break down each of the three pieces of my line:

```
 sed -E 's/([[:digit:]]{4})-([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{2}) ([[:digit:]]{2}):([[:digit:]]{2})/\1\2\3\4\5/' $logfile \
 | awk '{
     if ( ( $1 >= 201306090800 ) && ( $1 <= 201306091100 ) ) {
         print $0
     }
}'
```

Okay, a bit rough. The date and time are hard coded in the awk program, and the output will print out the date with all of the formatting stripped out. But, it will work.

It'll take a bit more work to smooth it out. For example, maybe have the user input the date and time range, and to reformat the date and time back into recognizable shape. However, will do what you want.

If you need multiple log files, you can use `cat` which in this case is not useless:

```
cat log* | sed -E 's/([[:digit:]]{4})-([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{2}) ([[:digit:]]{2}):([[:digit:]]{2})/\1\2\3\4\5/' | awk '{

     if ( ( $1 >= 201306090800 ) && ( $1 <= 201306091100 ) ) {
         print $0
     }
}'
```

The main idea is to message the data the way you want. This would be easier if you specified a more high level scripting language like Perl or Python. In fact, this is the very type of task that cause Larry Wall to invent Perl.

Answer (score 1):

if your date format is `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM`, it is relative easy, if I understood you correctly.

You could:

```
awk '$1" "$2>="2013-06-09 08:00" && $1" "$2 <= "2013-06-09 11:00"' *.log
```

the `*.log` will match all your 5 log files. it could be different pattern, e.g. `log.*` depends on your filenames.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a log viewer. There are many around, but one I used a while ago is [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/index.php).